# How to get the values from url with parameters to another url

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress for the website and I have a form which allows users to type in prices for each textbox...

As I click submit button, it processes into Paypal (process) - calculates the cost
It outputs the costs

Now the code is done by CASE:

- One is processing the paypal - **which is able to get the values from
  the textbox - using url parameters**

URL changes from the original website to the paypal website

- Other one is successfully purchased but **it is unable to get the
  values from the textbox - loses the values** **- this is need to update the database**

Is there something for PHP that can hold values throughout the process

This is my code for the process paypal

```
$bid1 = $_GET['cost1'];
$bid2 = $_GET['cost2'];
```

success paypal

```
echo $bid1;
// it shows up nothing
```

ANY HELP PLEASE =)

Comment: you want calculated cost after paypal process ?

Comment: So after completing the form as a user, it will direct the user to the paypal system to pay the 5% cost... after the user HAS paid, somehow I need to add those values of each item to the database, including the total costs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Paypal doesn't send the values back in any way, your other option would be to save the data using a cookie (client side) or session (server side). Both have security implications though.